# How to Setup Edge node for kerberized cluster

Tags: security, hadoop, active-directory, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

We need to setup a 6 node Hadoop cluster with one additional Edge node (where Hadoop client components need to be installed like, Hue, SQOOP). We are planning to make it as a kerberized cluster, additionally we are integrating each cluster node(All 6 nodes) with Microsoft AD using SSSD pattern.

How do we enable Kerberos on Edge node, since it will not co-exist with the cluster, and not available under Ambari UI scope.

Please suggest the way to solve this.

Comment: Just update `/etc/krb5.conf` to mirror what you've got on cluster nodes. That's the config used by `kinit` and by Kerberos clients to connect to the KDC. And, of course, make sure your machine has the "kerberos-workstation" system package installed (or the Ubuntu equivalent)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your comment

Comment: And, of course, use the same Hadoop `*-site.xml` config files on the Edge node, especially the property that sets Kerberos authentication...!